# Problem to install GAZEBO in Synaptic

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
when i "**Mark**" "**ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo**" in "**Synaptic**" when this package "**is not installed**" (in status!), wanna "**to be removed**" some ROS packages in list, when i click "**mark**". it gave me this error:

> **Can't Mark All Packages For Installation Or Upgrade**

> ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo: Depends: ros-fuerte-bullet (=2.79-s1359841903~precise) but 2.79-s1359842349~oneiric is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-common-msgs (=1.8.13-0precise-20130203-0848-+0000) but 1.8.13-0oneiric-20130203-0846-+0000 is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-common-rosdeps (=1.2.0-s1359838704~precise) but 1.2.0-s1359839413~oneiric is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-driver-common but it is not going to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry but it is not going to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-image-common but it is not going to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-nodelet-core (=1.6.5-s1359894314~precise) but 1.6.5-
> s1359892967~oneiric is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-perception-pcl but it is not going to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-robot-model but it is not going to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-ros (=1.8.10-0precise-20130202-2019-+0000) but 1.8.10-0oneiric-20130202-2019-+0000 is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-ros-comm (=1.8.15-0precise-20130203-0847-+0000) but 1.8.15-0oneiric-20130203-0849-+0000 is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-visualization-common (=1.8.4-s1359883358~precise) but 1.8.4-s1359886951~oneiric is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-xacro (=1.6.1-s1359883505~precise) but 1.6.1-s1359888901~oneiric is to be installed

> Depends: ros-fuerte-protobuf (=0.1.0-s1359883067~precise) but 0.1.0-s1359886619~oneiric is to be installed

what am i shoud to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56987/problem-to-install-gazebo-in-synaptic/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have some broken packages there. From the looks of your output there it's looking for ubuntu 12.04 packages, but can only find 11.10 packages. What distribution and version are you running?

---

Originally posted by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) with karma: 124 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0